# is there any way to enable telnet/ssh session into a Netgear CG3700EMR

Tags: router, ssh, wake-on-lan, arp

I want to enable Wake on Wan (Wol from internet) with my router, but i have no chance to modify arp table in order to specify a fake address which could receive this broadcast packet.

So, is there any way to get inside the device through ssn/telnet? Or, at least, any way to add this arp entry?

Answer (score 0):

Using DDWRT to replace firmware will let u do whatever you want with the NG.
There you have the link

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNDR3300